# How to check if value in filter exists?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying this code to set a filter to a value

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Client Code").CurrentPage _
        = "BUN"
```

but what if there is no BUN? how do I check if BUN exists or to skip if error?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotfield.pivotitems shows how to loop over the pivotitems collection

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:

```
Function HasNamedPivotItem(ByVal pvtField As Excel.PivotField, _
                           ByVal namedItem As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    HasNamedPivotItem = Not VBA.IsNull(pvtField.PivotItems(namedItem))
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

It attempts to reference the pivot value.  If it doesn't exist, an error occurs and it returns the default boolean value of `False`.  Otherwise it returns `True`.

Use it like this:

```
Sub Example()

    Dim myPvtField As Excel.PivotField
    Set myPvtField = Excel.ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Client Code")


    If HasNamedPivotItem(myPvtField, "BUN") = True Then
        MsgBox "Pivot field exists!"
    Else
        MsgBox "Pivot field does -NOT- exist."
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this, which is better? Also what if I need to do this for all the ones in the filter how would I do that? sux as BUN, CAX, CMN, GMN ect..
how do I do it without repeating the code?

```
   For Each pvtitem In ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Client 
   Code").PivotItems
   If pvtitem.Name = "CAX" Then
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Client Code").CurrentPage _
        = "CAX"
   Column1 = "AQ"
   Call Brand(Range1, Column1)
   Exit For
   End If
   Next
```